# Фокус элементов HTML формы с помощью нажатия комбинации клавиш

Tags: javascript, html

Атрибут `accesskey="клавиша"` дает фокус, но в него вписать можно только один символ:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="file" accesskey="5"/>
```

На элемент формы с `accesskey="12"` он не среагирует.

Как заставить браузер давать фокус на 12й `checkbox` при наборе `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `12` (`12` набирается на цифровой клавиатуре справа)?

Примечание: если 2 `checkbox`'a имеют номер 12, то должны помечаться оба.

Comment: В Opera 30.0, кстати, реагирует на `Alt + 5`. Это я к чему: если вам нужен единый вариант для всех браузеров и с числом больше 9, то стоит попробовать написать JS с отлавливанием нажатий клавиш в документе.

Comment: @Regent да, вы верно подметили. Это уловил. К сожалению, я ни чуть-чуть не понимаю в JS.

Comment: У меня есть предложение сделать без доп. клавиш (`Alt`, `Ctrl`, `Shift` и т.д.), но в этом случае могут возникать проблемы, если где-то нужно вводить текст. Однако проблем с `Alt` или `Ctrl` ничуть не меньше - в разных браузерах разная реакция на сочетания `Alt + 1` или `Ctrl + 1`, что приводит к невозможности их использования.

Comment: Если вас устраивает вариант без доп. клавиш (просто `5` или `12`), то решение с JS я разместить готов. Вариант решения проблемы ввода текста в другие поля (чтобы это не расценивалось как попытка выбрать `checkbox`) тоже есть, хоть и не очень изящный.

Comment: @Regent, мне кажется, что содружество Shift + Ctrl + цифра наиболее оптимально во всех браузерах и не будет затрагивать внутренние горячие клавиши браузера. Разве от набора клавиш кардинально меняется JS-код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Используется jQuery. При очень большом (и только при очень большом) желании можно переписать код без него.
- У каждого `checkbox`, выбор которого должен осуществляться c клавиатуры, задан атрибут `data-key` с числовым неотрицательным значением.
- `checkbox`'ы выбираются c помощью `Ctrl` + `Shift` + значение `data-key`.
- Макс. задержку между нажатиями клавиш можно варьировать с помощью переменной `keyPressMaxDelay`.
- Обрабатывается событие `keydown` - с событием `keypress` могут быть проблемы из-за `Ctrl` и `Shift`.
- При использовании NumPad `NUM LOCK` должен быть выключен.
- Протестировано на работоспособность в браузерах: Opera 30.0, Chrome 43.0, IE 11.0, Firefox 38.0.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numlockFix = [45, 35, 40, 34, 37, 12, 39, 36, 38, 33];
    var pressed = "";
    var timeoutId = 0;
    var keyPressMaxDelay = 400;
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (timeoutId > 0) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        var which = e.which;
        for (var i = 0; i < numlockFix.length; i++) {
            if (numlockFix[i] == which) {
                which = i + 48;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && which >= 48 && which <= 57) {
            pressed += which - 48;
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
                $('input[data-key=' + pressed + ']').trigger('click');
                pressed = "";
            }, keyPressMaxDelay);
        } else {
            pressed = "";
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-key="5"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-key="12"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: каким образом расширить диапазон чисел, нужно от 0000 до 2359, то есть для выбора чекбоксов по времени?

Comment: код не срабатывает при наборе на отдельной цифровой клавиатуре, расположенной, обычно, справа.

Comment: @koji на данный момент никаких ограничений по длине числа нет. Можно использовать хоть `99999`: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/dLe10k2j/).

Comment: @koji с NumPad одни сплошные проблемы при зажатых `Ctrl` + `Shift`. Вам точно нужен именно NumPad? И NumLock должен быть включен или выключен?

Comment: @koji с выключенным `Num Lock` можно проблему решить так: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/dLe10k2j/1/). С включенным - всё очень плохо.

Comment: Подумал, что при отключенном `Num Lock` вполне можно нажимать на цифры без `Ctrl` + `Shift` клавиш, хотя при этом меняется положение курсора на цифрах `4` `6` `2` `8`. Будет в этой ситуации срабатывать `checkbox` ?

Comment: @koji код рассчитан на использование с `Ctrl` + `Shift`. Если уберёте проверку на `Ctrl` и `Shift` для клавиш с NumPad, то срабатывать будет.

Comment: вы имеете в виду `17` `23` `24` `25` строки (из примера в комментариях) ?

Comment: @koji я имею в виду, что при нажатии на клавишу с NumPad (то есть при попадании `e.which` в `numlockFix`) не проверять нажаты ли `Ctrl` и `Shift`. Так как это уже доработка, а не часть вопроса, то я хотел, чтобы вы попробовали сделать это самостоятельно, но всё же сделал [пример этого](http://jsfiddle.net/dLe10k2j/2/).

Comment: Regent, мне казалось, что потребуется убрать `e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey` из кода чтобы можно было использовать набор с `NumPad` без доп.клавиш, но вы их почему-то оставили, а почему?

Comment: @koji для сохранения возможности использования `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `цифры в основной части клавиатуры`.

Comment: Уверен, эта возможность не потребуется, так как предложенный вами вариант с отключенным NumPad оправдал себя на 100%. Как будет выглядеть код, [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/kojiko/4kde538w/) ?

Comment: @koji примерно, но вы удалили и важный код. Должно [быть так](http://jsfiddle.net/4kde538w/1/).